# Conflicting overloads: public constructor ApiSuccessResponse<T>(body: T)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm copying the [Google's code from their repository of samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/api/ApiResponse.kt) implementing Android Architecture Components, slowly adapting to the needs of the app I have in mind, using the code as a base. I have reached already a part where for me is displaying an error and I can't understand why. This is the code block:

```
data class ApiSuccessResponse<T>(val responseBody: T) : ApiResponse<T>() {
    constructor(body: T) : this (responseBody = body)
}
```

The error message underlying is

> Conflicting overloads: public constructor ApiSuccessResponse(body: T) defined in com.example.rxe.api.ApiSuccessResponse, public constructor ApiSuccessResponse(responseBody: T) defined in com.example.rxe.api.ApiSuccessResponse

Here's where I call `ApiSuccessResponse`, just like in the sample code:

```
sealed class ApiResponse<T> {
    companion object {
        fun <T> create(response: Response<T>): ApiResponse<T> {
            return if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val responseBody = response.body()

                if (responseBody == null || response.code() == 204) {
                    ApiEmptyResponse()
                } else {
                    ApiSuccessResponse(body = responseBody)
                }
            } else {
                val error = response.errorBody()?.string()
                val message = if (error.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    response.message()
                } else {
                    error
                }

                ApiErrorResponse(errorMessage = message ?: "Unknown error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something might have changed since the sample has been written. But if I rename the variable to `body` instead of `responseBody`, the same error will underline the call for the class `ApiSuccessResponse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to understand how [constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) work in Kotlin. This is the code you tried to copy:

```
data class ApiSuccessResponse<T>(
    val body: T,
    val links: Map<String, String>
) : ApiResponse<T>() {
    constructor(body: T, linkHeader: String?) : this(
        body = body,
        links = linkHeader?.extractLinks() ?: emptyMap()
    )
    //.... rest of body
}
```

It has two constructors:

1. Primary constructor: `ApiSuccessResponse(body: T, links: Map<String, String>)`
2. Secondary constructor: `ApiSuccessResponse(body: T, linkHeader: String?)` (which extracts map of links from `String` and passes it as `links` into primary).

What you have is:

1. Primary constructor: `ApiSuccessResponse(resposebody: T)`
2. Secondary constructor: `ApiSuccessResponse(body: T)` (which tries to call primary constructor 1:1, but it just clashes due to identical signature)

If you don't need secondary constructor You should just delete it entirely.